# state variable to open & close Mui's Backdrop changing automatically on hovering speed dial

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to implement Material UI's Backdrop and Speed dial component.
in the end, it will look something like this

[image]

Here's my sample code

```
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [hidden, setHidden] = React.useState(false);


  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log('open',open)
  },[open])
```

Calling backdrop and speed dial :-

```
<Backdrop open={open} className={classes.backDrop} />
<SpeedDial
   ariaLabel="SpeedDial tooltip example"
   className={classes.speedDial}
   hidden={hidden}
   icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
   onClose={handleClose}
   onOpen={handleOpen}
   open={open}
>
   {actions.map((action) => (
      <SpeedDialAction
          key={action.name}
          icon={action.icon}
          tooltipTitle={action.name}
          tooltipOpen
          onClick={handleClose}
       />
    ))}
 </SpeedDial>
```

problem is that, when i comment out this line

```
<Backdrop open={open} className={classes.backDrop} />
```

speed dial opens as it should be, but when I uncomment the line calling Backdrop, my controlling state variable i.e open, first changes to true, then automatically becomes false when I hover on Speed dial.
what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on codesandbox?

Comment: Also where's the function `handleVisibility` called? Why is it even defined?

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: You've passed hidden to `SpeedDial` which is always false. I think that's causing the problem.

Comment: no, that's not the issue

Comment: here's codesandbox sample

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-microservice-l27dt?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the `zIndex` of the `backDrop`.

Just removing it made your component working.

---

Still, if you want to give `zIndex` to it, just increase the `zIndex` of your speed dial by 1 of that of `backDrop`

```
speedDial: {
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: '4%',
      right: '3%',
      zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 2,
  },
  backDrop: {
      zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
      color: '#fff',
    },
```